# Display db column data by index instead of name?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, razor

I have a simple Partial View that gets a db's schema (column names) from the controller in a ViewBag. I would like to then roll out the row data without having to specify the column names as I have done here, in order to make it "schema agnostic" like the ViewBag columns are.
The controller SQL query to gather the column names is:

```
"SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Sales'"
```

The Partial View is here:

```
@model App.Models.AppModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
 <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @{foreach (var ColumnName in ViewBag.DbColumnNames)
            {
                    <th>@ColumnName</th>
            }
        </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>

        @{foreach (var ColumnData in Model.Sales)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@ColumnData.ItemId</td>
                    <td>@ColumnData.Item</td>
                    <td>ColumnData.Description</td>
                    <td>@ColumnData.Qty</td>
                    <td>@ColumnData.Price</td>
                    <td>@ColumnData.LineTotal</td>
                    <td>@ColumnData.SaleNo</td>
                    <td>@ColumnData.Taxable</td>
                    <td>@ColumnData.Memo</td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Loop through the model's properties, add a <td> for each of them.

Comment: Can't loop though it. I tried that. It doesn't contain a GetEnumerator.

Comment: No, it requires reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Can't loop though it. I tried that. It doesn't contain a GetEnumerator. I have to make the db record Enumerable so I could foreach it. What I came up with is probably retarded and wrong but it works. For each record found in the dbcontext I convert it so a json string then convert it back to a variable and this gave me a record I could loop through with foreach and refer to each item as item.Value only as what is returned from the json decode is a key/value pair. This has resulted in what I wanted, A db editor / viewer that abstracts the schema away so the code never has to change if the schema does. - and it will.